# Proof of variance reduction of bagging

Tags: statistics, finance-mathematics, machine-learning

In Lecture 4 of the following course:

```
Advances in Financial Machine Learning: 10 Lectures
by Marcos Lopez de Prado
```

[link](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3257420)

in the proof of variance reduction for a bagged estimator at page 8, I do not understand why we have the following equality:
$$ \sum_{j \neq i}^{N} \bar{\sigma}^2 \bar{\rho} = \sum_{j \neq i}^{N} \sigma_i \sigma_j \rho_{i,j}
$$